# Showing that an estimator for covariance is consistent?

Tags: statistics, covariance, variance

I'm having trouble proving that a certain estimator is consistent. I know that to show an estimator is consistent, I have to show that the variance of the estimator approaches zero as n grows large/goes to infinity.

The estimator for $Cov(X_i,Y_i)$ from a random sample $(X_i,Y_i)$ for $i = (1, ... , n)$ is as follows:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_{i}-\overline{X})(Y_i-\overline{Y})$$

I let $\hat{\theta}$ be the estimator and thought that doing this would work:

$$V(\hat{\theta}) = V(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_{i}Y_{i}-X_{i}\overline{Y}-Y_{i}\overline{X}+\overline{X} \overline{Y}))$$

I expanded the terms but I have no idea how to go from here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can begin by using the formula
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i - \bar{X}\right)\left(Y_i - \bar{Y}\right)
= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i Y_i - \bar{X} \bar{Y}
$$

> **Proof.**
>   $$ \begin{aligned} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i - \bar{X}\right)\left(Y_i - \bar{Y}\right) &=  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n
> \left(X_i Y_i - X_i \bar{Y} - Y_i \bar{X} + \bar{X} \bar{Y}\right) \\
> &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i Y_i - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i
> \bar{Y} - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \bar{X} + \frac{1}{n}
> \sum_{i=1}^n \bar{X} \bar{Y} \\ &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i Y_i -
> \bar{Y} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \bar{X} \frac{1}{n}
> \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i + \bar{X} \bar{Y} \\ &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i
> Y_i - \bar{Y} \bar{X} - \bar{X} \bar{Y} + \bar{X} \bar{Y} \\ &=
> \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i Y_i - \bar{X} \bar{Y} \end{aligned} $$

Next, by the [weak law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law), the quantities $\bar{X}$, $\bar{Y}$, and $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i Y_i$ converge in probability to $E[X_i]$, $E[Y_i]$, and $E[X_i Y_i]$, respectively.
By two applications of [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem#Statement), it follows that $\bar{X} \bar{Y}$ converges in probability to $E[X_i] E[Y_i]$ and hence that
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i Y_i - \bar{X} \bar{Y}
$$
converges in probability to $E[X_i Y_i] - E[X_i] E[Y_i] = \operatorname{Cov}(X_i, Y_i)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful.

Comment: Why do we require two applications of Slutsky's theorem instead of one?

Comment: @MattiaMariantoni once for the convergence of $\bar{X}\bar{Y}$, then again for the convergence of $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i Y_i - \bar{X} \bar{Y}$.